# How to find out if value in column is in list of values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get rows of dataFrame if value in some column is in the list of acceptable values. So I'm trying to get series of bool values first to use them for dataframe indexing.

I'm getting ***ValueError***: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
Why is that and how can I solve my task?

```
c = ['m','n','a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':c})
df['c'] == 'm'                    #works
df['c'] in ['m','x']              #valueError!
df['c'] == 'm' or df['c'] == 'x'  #same error! Why?
```

Comment: `df['c'].isin(['m','x'])` and   `(df['c'] == 'm' )|( df['c'] == 'x')`

Comment: @Wen-Ben quick work, but would be better as an answer, no?

Comment: @G.Anderson very common question :-)

Comment: Right, that lol. nvm! :)